# How to read the below data to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the data in the below variable

```py
ohlc = 
"1664788799|38444.9|38569.2|38327.85|38412.35|0|0|,1664789099|38408.35|38587.3|38394.05|38586.15|0|0|,1664789399|38589.55|38641.6|38420.05|38422.35|0|0|"
```

The columns are timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume, OI

How do we convert this pythion variable to dataframe. Any simple way to do this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. Please format your code appropriately for some more clarity on the required solution. Is the variable stored as a single string? Is it a list? Is it a CSV file stored on disk?

Comment: its in a variable stored as a single string

Comment: Is it | for separating columns and a , for separating each row?

Comment: yes.. thats how the data is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string into lists using the two separators and then pass the list of lists to the dataframe constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [row.split('|')[:-1] for row in ohlc.split(',')],
    columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'OI']
)
```

Output:

```
     timestamp      open       high      low       close    volume  OI
0   1664788799   38444.9    38569.2 38327.85    38412.35         0   0
1   1664789099  38408.35    38587.3 38394.05    38586.15         0   0
2   1664789399  38589.55    38641.6 38420.05    38422.35         0   0
```

P.S. You can add `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` to convert all columns to numeric values (integers/floats).

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is stored in a single string with "|" and "," used as separators, you can use Python's `str.split` method to get a list of values. In the data there's also an addiitonal sep character at the end which needs to be removed. To do this we can use `str.replace` using tab characters and `str.strip` to remove the trailing separator.

For converting the string into a CSV like object Pandas can read, we can use `StringIO` class from the `io` builtin module.

```py
import io

ohlc = "1664788799|38444.9|38569.2|38327.85|38412.35|0|0|,1664789099|38408.35|38587.3|38394.05|38586.15|0|0|,1664789399|38589.55|38641.6|38420.05|38422.35|0|0|"

rows = [row.replace('|', '\t').strip() for row in ohlc.split(',')]
rows_tsv = '\n'.join(rows)

header = ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'OI']

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(rows_tsv), sep='\t', header=None))
df.columns = header  # to use the header names as required
```